# Are moderators notified by the system when a user has serial votes reversed?

Tags: discussion, flags, serial-voting, moderators

I was wondering if moderators ever get notified whenever a serial voting reversal event occurs for some user?

For example, if a user who's got a bunch of duplicate accounts that he's using to fraudulently upvote all of his own content, one day gets a bunch of serial upvotes reversed by the system, does the system try to alert moderators to that event, in case a follow-up investigation of the user is needed? Or do moderators only find out about these events when someone points it out to them, or they stumble upon the information themselves?

If moderators aren't notified, *should* we be flagging users that get serial upvotes reversed for further investigation? What about serial downvoting victims?

Comment: It seems like the point of automatic reversal is so that moderators don't have to be notified.

Comment: I was going to ask a similar question, but I think this covers it - I wanted to know if, when a large number of serial votes I have received are reversed, whether I should also notify a moderator to deal with the miscreant. However, it seems that the point of the system is to take the load of the moderator, so I won't also report.

Answer (score 30):

No. We're not notified of these events.

If we were we'd probably be overwhelmed with notifications.

Comment: I figured as much.

Comment: If you investigate some users, do those reversals show up prominently?

Comment: @Deduplicator - reversals do show up. It's clear enough, but I'm not sure whether it would be called "prominently" though.

Comment: If you look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1197918/jeb11?tab=reputation) on June 19th you can see the effect of a serial upvoting reversal.  Not sure if that's what you mean by "show up prominently".  I suspect the upvoter was user `cudoer` but I don't know if there is any way to tell that from a non-moderator perspective.

Comment: Even from a moderator perspective, it's quite difficult to get the user involved in such. It can be done, but it's quite difficult...