# Serial voting was reversed, but wrongly earned badges remain?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, serial-voting

Recently I have been serially up-voted, which caused by reputation to reach the daily limit of `200`, by which in turn I achieved the <kbd>Mortarboard</kbd> badge, erroneously.

[image: achievements]

As you can see in the above image, the unjustified reputation gain has been reversed correctly. However, the badge is still there; I expected it to be removed too.

Is this the intentional behaviour, or is this a flaw in the algorithms for (reputation- and score-dependent) badge achievements?

Comment: I think this is by design. Badges are never retracted when the conditions for them are no longer met, but won't be re-awarded the next time around.

Comment: @yellowantphil I would be surprised if mods don't handle a user who's votes get reverted several times.

Comment: @Tom, according to [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267879), moderators do not get notified when users get their votes automatically reverted, so how should they know...

Comment: @aschipfl Frankly, we don't care. If they're voting in a way that the system always corrects, then there's not much action to take on it. The invalidated votes don't contribute to the silver and gold versions of this badge later on. We *do* get reports of suspicious votes that are not caught by the system, so that they can be looked into further. But even then, I rarely contact the users about it. There's a nice link already there in the reputation history that explains what happened. Unless I need to suspend them, I just invalidate and move on.

Comment: @aschipfl: Time to get a new T-shirt: I got serial upvoted and all I was left with was this lousy badge...